# giving app permissions to read my graph api for active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0

For application permissions, the effective permissions of your app will be the full level of privileges implied by the permission. For example, an app that has the User.ReadWrite.All application permission can update the profile of every user in the organization.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

Question:  How and where do I give my app permission to user.readwrite.all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Azure AD v1 endpoint, then you can provide the permissions to Microsoft Graph API by going to the Azure AD application registration page where you can select which kind of permissions you want to give e.g. application or delegated permissions. On portal page you can go to Settings of the application and use "Required Permissions" blade to add respective API, in your case it would "Microsoft Graph" and then selecting the required permissions level. In your case "User.ReadWrite.All" will be listed as "Read and Write all user's full profiles" in the permissions list. Please find below the screenshots -

[image]
and
[image]

You can also refer to [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/21/finding-the-correct-permissions-for-a-microsoft-or-azure-active-directory-graph-call/) which talks about adding the correct Permissions for Microsoft Graph or Azure Active Directory API call.

Please refer to [blog](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/application-permission-with-v2-endpoint-and-microsoft-graph/) if you are using Azure AD v2 enpoint.  You can also refer to know the difference between v1 and v2 endpoints over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison).

Comment: I have a testapp and a prod app registered. I do not know why, but the developer before me got the testapp working, but for some reason i cannot get the prod app working.  i've done the above exactly as you've told me.  I get this error:  System.Exception: methodname: Graph API failed for path: groups/xxxxx/members, tid: 123456. Reason: Forbidden     at .....MoveNext() in C:\

Comment: can you tell me if there could be a different reason I am still getting this forbidden response?

Comment: It could be some permissions issue.  Can you try providing admin consent to the application.